# New enum with array

Tags: java, enums

I need to save enum values (`MERIA` and `SMI` in this case) from a list of strings created by `split()`.

Here is what I have:

```
public AccessLevel[] getAccess() {
    String Access = "MERIA : SMI";
    String[] split = Access.split(" : ");
    for (String Acces : split) {
        list.add(AccessLevel.valueOf(Acces));
    }
    return new AccessLevel[]{AccessLevel.MERIA,AccessLevel.NONE};
}
```

I want something like this, with the enum parameters from the list saved into an array:

```
 public AccessLevel[] getAccess() {
    String Access = "MERIA : SMI";
    String[] split = Access.split(" : ");
    for (String Acces : split) {
        list.add(AccessLevel.valueOf(Acces));
    } 
    return new AccessLevel[]{list};

}
```

Comment: sorry corrected

Comment: need to be transmitted AccessLevel.MERIA, AccessLevel.NONE to AccessLevel in array

Comment: select several enums from AccessLevel and return them in enum [] format

Comment: OK downvote removed since it's more clear what you're asking now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new array using the length `split.length`.

```
public AccessLevel[] getAccess() {
    String access = "MERIA : SMI";
    String[] split = access.split("\\s*:\\s*");
    AccessLevel[] accessLevels = new AccessLevel[split.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        accessLevels[i] = AccessLevel.valueOf(split[i]);
    }
    return accessLevels;
}
```

Also note that I changed `" : "` to `"\\s*:\\s*"` to cater any number of spaces. Alternatively, you can use `String.trim()`.

And non-final variable names in java start with lower-case letters.

---

Or you can use the Stream API:-

```
public AccessLevel[] getAccess() {
    String access = "MERIA : SMI";
    return Arrays.stream(access.split(":"))
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(AccessLevel::valueOf)
            .toArray(AccessLevel[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### problems

there are a number of problems with your code:

1. `Access` should be `access`
   in java it is convention to type a lower case letter at the start of a variable and an upper case letter at the start of a class name, that way classes en variables are easily distinguishable

but mainly

2. `list` doesn't exist so you should make a variable.

### solutions

### arrays

```
public AccessLevel[] getAccess() {
    String accessesString = "MERIA : SMI";
    String[] split = accessesString.split(" : ");

    AccessLevel[] list = new AccessLevel[split.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        list[i] = AccessLevel.valueOf(split[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

### List

you should really use List instead of basic arrays, they're more versatile and easier to use.

```
public List<AccessLevel> getAccess() {
    String accessesString = "MERIA : SMI";
    String[] split = accessesString.split(" : ");

    List<AccessLevel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String access : split) {
        list.add(AccessLevel.valueOf(access));
    }
    return list;
}
```

### Streams

The most elegant solutions in my opinion but maybe a bit more difficult.

```
public List<AccessLevel> getAccess() {
    String accessesString = "MERIA : SMI";
    String[] split = accessesString.split(" : ");

    return Arrays.stream(split)
            .map(AccessLevel::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I hope that was helpful!
greetz